# AutoPostBack also initializes the style value changed in js

Tags: asp.net

```
 <tr style="display: none;">
                            <td><input id="ck1" runat="server" type="checkbox"></td>
                            <td><asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlProductName1" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProductName1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="ddlSupliersName1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:Textbox id="unitPrice1" name="unitPirce" runat="server" OnTextChanged="unitPrice1_TextChanged" /></td>
                            <td><input id="quantity1" type="text" name="quantity" runat="server" /></td>
                            <td><input id="discount1" type="text" name="discount" runat="server"/></td>
                            <td><span id="subtotal1"></span></td>
                        </tr>
```

```
var currentRowIndex = 0;
        var maxRowIndex = 9;

        function rowAdd() {
            if (currentRowIndex <= maxRowIndex) {
                var row = document.getElementById('myTable').rows[currentRowIndex + 1];
                row.style.display = '';
                currentRowIndex++;
            }
        }
```

When you click the button, the display that was none is displayed. Is there a way to solve this?
I tried updatePannel, but it was the same

I want to keep the changed style='' value using js